# Mysql with multiple query having NAND opertaion and NOT operation

Tags: mysql, database, operators, logic

I am trying to achieve and NOT operation and NAND operation in between Queries.

## Scenario 1:

```
 SELECT 
    country_name,country_code 
       from country 
       where not (country_name='Land islands' and country_code='AX');
```

Works well; Shows all other countries other than the two country which I am mentioning.

## Scenario 2:

When I try with some select inside the where condition it shows errors.

```
 SELECT * from
   country 
     where not 
       (SELECT * from country 
              where country_name='Land islands' 
        and 
        SELECT * from country
               where country_code='AX');
```

It shows an error..

[Kindly refer the Link:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16438440/mysql-nand-nor-operations-in-queries) With my previous question and the working of NOT and NAND operation.

[MySQL NAND/NOR operations in Queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16438440/mysql-nand-nor-operations-in-queries)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AND` should be replaced by `UNION` and the `primary key` of table (let it assume `id`) should be checked with `NOT IN` clause.

```
SELECT * from country 
WHERE id NOT IN
       (SELECT id from country 
              where country_name='Land islands' 
        UNION
        SELECT id from country
               where country_code='AX'
        );
```